# How to parse a JSON that contains u' characters?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I want to get the `blank fill` array but the `arrayB` that I get is `nil`. How should I do this?

JSON:

```
{
    result =     {
        blankfill = "[[1, [u'', u'', u'', u''], False, 0]]";
        choice = "[[1599, [1], False, 2], [1598, [1], False, 5], [1596, [1], True, 4], [1594, [1], True, 2], [1593, [1], False, 2], [1592, [1], False, 2]]";
        spendTime = 20;
    };
    retcode = 0;
    subjectid = 1;
    submittime = "2016-05-07T18:43:35.094";
}
```

Code:

```
NSString *jsonStringB = [responseObject[@"result"] objectForKey:@"blankfill"];
NSString *jsonSB = [jsonStringB stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"False" withString:@"false"];
NSString *jsonSBA = [jsonSB stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"True" withString:@"true"];

NSData *dataB = [jsonSBA dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSArray *arrayB = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataB options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

for (NSArray *arr in arrayB) {
    TaskConditonModel *model = [[TaskConditonModel alloc] init];
    [model initModelWithArray:arr];
    [self.blankfillArray addObject:model];
}
```

Comment: Maybe you need to replace occurrences of `''` with `'`.

Comment: Json is not in valid formate check here - http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: The JSON ins't in valid format because I think the JSON @Simon has posted in the question isnt the original JSON. He must posted it by printing the parsed object in the console.

Comment: {
    result =     {
        blankfill = "[[1, [u'x', u'', u'', u''], False, 7]]";
        choice = "[[1565, [0], False, 5], [896, [1], True, 4], [892, [0], False, 2]]";
        spendTime = 18;
    };
    retcode = 0;
    subjectid = 1;
    submittime = "2016-05-07T18:42:57.638";
}